# How to create unpaid invoice programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating an invoice by running cron job after order completion, but it creates an invoice with status 'Paid'. I want invoice to be created with status 'Pending'. 
This is the code i am using for creating invoice

```
$invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();
$invoice->register();
Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($invoice)
    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
    ->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    $capture = Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::NOT_CAPTURE;
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice */
    $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
    $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase($capture);
    $invoice->register();

    $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
        ->addObject($invoice)
        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

    $transaction->save();
```

The `$capture` is one of the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice` predefined values (const):

```
const CAPTURE_ONLINE   = 'online';
const CAPTURE_OFFLINE  = 'offline';
const NOT_CAPTURE      = 'not_capture';
```

#### UPDATE:

If you want to have ability to manage capture of the COD payment method, you need to rewrite the `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cashondelivery` and add to it:

```
protected $_canCapture = true;
```

After that you can use "capture case" with no capture value when creating a new invoice and capture that invoice later using the capture button on the invoice view page:

[image: Result]

Comment: Same result . Invoice created with status 'Paid' .

Comment: @Nafees What payment method you are using for order?

Comment: Cash on Delivery

Comment: @Nafees Unfortunately it is inaccessible for the COD method, because the COD method can't be captured later by default

Comment: @Nafees I've updated my answer

Comment: @Nafees I'm glad to help you :)

Comment: you also should pass $qtys array to  ->prepareInvoice()