# Invoice to be sent after "Bank Transfer" transaction

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, invoice

I want to send invoice to customer after they place an order using the "Bank Transfer" method.

It only sends the invoice one the payment is "taken" but I want to send the invoice as soon as the order is placed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create an observer on `sales_order_place_after` and check the payment method (or use the module's observer if they have a custom one)

Then you can create the invoice:

```
$capture = Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::NOT_CAPTURE;
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice */
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase($capture);
$invoice->register();

$transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($invoice)
    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

$transaction->save();
```

(source: [How to create unpaid invoice programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112935/how-to-create-unpaid-invoice-programmatically))

Comment: Thank you for directing me! I will let you know how it went once I go through it and will accept the answer!